# Using cypress, how to prevent Anuglar app from reloading when browsing DOM snapshots history

Tags: angular, cypress

I am trying to do E2E tests of Anuglar webcomponent using Cypress. Tests themselves are running smothly. However, when I try to incspec DOM snapshots by howeving/clicking on test body log on the left side, instead of seeing a "static" DOM snapshot as it were at given time, app reinitializes itself in the test frame (or navigates? hard to tell).

Is it normal behavior when using Angular with Cypress, or there is something wrong with my cypress or app setup.

Altough I didnt create a reproduceable example (as I dont know how to force/prevent the issue from happening) and I cannot share the code nor screenshots, the behavior very similar to the one described here
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5776

with the exception that in my case snapshot can be blank or can contain some strange artifacts or even first page of my app.